# Convergence of Fourier series when $f(x)$ is defined on mixed interval

Tags: fourier-series, uniform-convergence

I was wondering if you have a periodic, piecewise $C^1$ continuous function $f(x)$ defined on a mixed interval, e.g. $[-1, 1)$, if the $FS f(x)$ still converges uniformly on $[-1, 1)$? You know that $f(-1) = f(1)$.

[Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFKbj.png)

[Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS39V.jpg)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich updated the question. From my book "basic partial differential equations", this should be enough to say that $f(x)$ converges uniformly if the interval is closed.

Comment: Piecewise $C^1$ implies Hölder continuity, which in turn implies uniform convergence.

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, but it also holds for a mixed interval?

Comment: @Jose27  No,  continuity on $[-1,1]$ plus piecewise $C^1$ on $[-1,1)$ does not imply Holder continuity on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich see the theorem in the question, it states that this information is enough for uniform convergence

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Doesn't piecewise $C^1$ require one sided limits for derivatives? (I was always taught this way, maybe it's nonstandard?)

Comment: So, what exactly is the difference between the problem on a mixed interval and a closed interval? Are you saying that at the join $x=1$ we might fail to be piecewise $C^1$?

Comment: @Kimmen The theorem states that that's enough to get uniform convergence _on_ a compact interval. I don't know why you think I"m disputing that...

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, the problem is precisely that "piecewise $C^1$ on $[-1,1)$" does not imply $f'$ has a limit at $1$. (It does imply $f'$ has one-sided lmits at every point of $[-1,1)$.)

Comment: @Jose27  Okay, I am pretty new to Fourier. I added the task I tried to solve in the question. Would you be able to help me with it?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, sorry I didn't understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the answer to the Question is no.

*But*  you should ask about the question you really care about! The Fourier series for the triangle function $f$ in the "task" you added to a later version does converge uniformly on the line.

(In fact that function is piecewise $C^1$ on $[-1,1]$, making it very unclear where the question about $[-1,1)$ came from...)